# Android spinner dropdown item ripple background goes outside the round corners

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-spinner, ripple-effect

I have an  `AppCompatSpinner` with a dropdown menu custom background with rounded corners. When I tap an option in the `AppCompatSpinner`, it shows the ripple background however the ripple goes outside the round corners and forms a normal rectangle. How can i make it so that the ripple fit in the background of popup?

This is how it looks now, ripple effect goes out of rounded background:

[image]

Im using `popupBackground` property to set rounded corners background.

MyActivity:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    popupBackground="@drawable/background_white_corners"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="50dp"
 ...
/>
```

background_white_corners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<shape ... android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <corners android:radius ="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

My item spinner is just a TextView, without any layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView ...
      android:id="@+id/textview_spinner_item"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ripple tag inside background drawable for ripple effect in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<ripple ....>
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
  <corners android:radius ="30dp"/>
  </shape>
</ripple>
```

Comment: I added ripple tag inside background drawable and nothing happenned, still doing the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [setClipToOutline(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setClipToOutline(boolean)) on the AppCompatSpinner.

You could also do it in the XML with [android:clipToOutline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:clipToOutline) but it's available in API 31+ only

Comment: I tried both and nothing happened, still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and nothing help :(

1. You can try transparent color in `colorControlHighlight` but this will work for all components and only in main app theme (not in PopupMenu, AutoCompleteTextView or Spinner styles).
2. You can use this trick (example) for AutoCompleteTextView

**AutoCompleteTextViewStyle**

```
<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_autocomplete</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_text</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/shape_selector</item>
        <item name="popupMenuBackground">@drawable/shape_selector</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/transparent_ripple</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/transparent_ripple</item>
</style>
```

**shape_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_shape"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/default_corner"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**transparent_ripple.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <ripple android:color="@color/color_transparent">
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@color/color_blue_light"/>
                    <corners android:radius="@dimen/default_corner"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
</selector>
```

P.S. Maybe anyone have same expirience? I can't repeat this fix for `PopupMenu` with round corners, parent from `Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner`